# Drools guided rule editor and Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, editor, drools, rule

I have created a java project in eclipse which automatically picks up 
all the .drl files from an external directory and executes all the 
rules in that directory .So this enables the execution of dynamic 
addition of new rules at anytime. 
Now, instead of creating a new drool file and add it into that 
directory, i want to use the guided rule editor to help non technical 
users to add new rules into that directory. 
I have started on with drools-workbench, but still i have no idea how 
to integrate this eclipse project with the guided rule editor feature 
available in drools-wb.

Is there any way in which i can export this project into the drools 
workbench. If that is possible, then how can i deploy this directory 
which contains all the .drl files into drools-wb and how these .drl 
files can be used in the guided rule editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your existing project is a maven project then you can import that project into drools-workbench, but there should be some required files(project.import,..etc) need to available specific to drools-workbench those should be available into project.  We cant download any specific rule file from drools-workbench, workbench will create jar file which contains all the assets(rules and BPMN files), you can add this jar into classpath and create kieSession from there through which you can execute rules.